# Obtener resto entre dos arrays PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

**Hola camaradas:**

En esta ocasión necesito de su ayuda, mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un script en PHP el cual busca emails en un txt y los filtra.

lo que necesito hacer es que mi script haga un cuenta entre los emails ya filtrados y los registrados, busque una igualdad entre ellos y si hay igualdad, que me devuelva el resto y me lo muestre en pantalla, osea tengo 1000 emails y 100 registrados, me tendria que devolver 900 emails no registrados.

lo que tengo echo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
$cont = 0;
$fichero_email = array('copia-emails.txt');
$fichero_salida = 'salida.txt';
$fichero_registrados = array('registrados.txt');
$fichero_limpio = array($fichero_salida);
$emails_unicos = array();
foreach ($fichero_email as $fichero_limpio) {
    $new = file_get_contents($fichero_limpio);
    preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $new, $resultado);
    foreach ($resultado[0] as $result) {
        if (!in_array($result, $emails_unicos)) {
            $emails_unicos[] = $result;
            $cont++;
        }else {
            count($fichero_registrados);
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents($fichero_salida, $emails_unicos, FILE_APPEND);
echo 'Usuarios no registrados: '. $cont;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es [**array_diff**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php), una función propia de PHP que te compara $array1 con uno o más arrays y te devuelve los valores de $array1 que no estén presentes en ninguno de los otros.

Según el ejemplo de la documentación oficial:

```
$array1    = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2    = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$resultado = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

En la variable `$resultado` te devolvería un array que contendría el valor blue, ya que es el único valor de `$array1` que no se encuentra en `$array2`.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que busco.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que buscas exactamente?

Comment: Contar los datos de los registrados, y si hay alguna coincidencia entre los dos arrays tanto el de salida como el de los registrados, que me devuelva el resto por ejemplo: tengo 1000 registrados y 2000 emails, va a ver 1000 coincidencias entonces, me tiene que devolver el resto que son 1000 emails no registrados.

Comment: @CristianAmirGarcia Eso es lo que te haría esta función. Tu le pasas como primer parámetro el array en el que están contenidos todos los emails y como segundo parámetro le pasas el array de los emails registrados. Como resultado te devolverá un array con todos los emails no registrados.

Comment: ese es el problema, no quier que me devuelva un array, sino que quiero que me de el numero exacto de los emails que quedan sin registrar. por ejemplo quedan 300 usuarios sin registrar

Comment: Entonces simplemente tendrías que hacer `count($resultado)` y te devolvería la cantidad de emails no registrados en número.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `array_diff()` para obtener las diferencias de email y luego `count()` para obtener el numero de emails diferentes.

```
$email = new stdClass();
$email->all =  ["a@a.a","b@b.b","c@c.c"];
$email->finded = ["b@b.b"];
$email->diff = new stdClass();
$email->diff->values = array_diff($email->all, $email->finded);
$email->diff->count = count($email->diff->values); 
print_r($email->diff);
```